# Replacement for ExpressionHelper in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

In ASP.NET Core 2.x I was using static method `GetExpressionText` of `ExpressionHelper` class for `IHtmlHelper<T>` extension method:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetExpressionText<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal` is not available any more. Therefore compiler is throwing exception:

> The name 'ExpressionHelper' does not exist in the current context.

What is proper replacement for `ExpressionHelper` functionality?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ModelExpressionProvider` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures` can be used.

Method `GetExpressionText` wraps identical method of `ExpressionHelper` and adds additional caching or results as described in this [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8678#issuecomment-475000503).

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetExpressionText<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var expressionProvider = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetService(typeof(ModelExpressionProvider)) as ModelExpressionProvider;

        return expressionProvider.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if not using a View? Like for an API. I am not sure why any sort of ViewContext is needed for `GetExpressionText`.

Comment: `GetExpressionText` is mainly used to render HTML element ids and names for the purpose of Model Binding, thus extension for IHtmlHelper<TModel> fits majority of use cases.
You can use it from an API as well. All you need is to obtain instance of `ModelExpressionProvider`. Simplest would probably be to get it via dependency injection in Controller constructor.

Comment: Thanks. My use case is a little more complicated. I actually need it in a automapper profile. Unfortunately profiles registered via built-in assembly scanning do not support injecting things. They must have an empty constructor. So I have just found other snippets to do what I need to do which is essentially converting an expression property chain to a string which is a little simpler then getexpressiontext.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution which does not depend on IHtmlHelper and can be used on other scenarios is the following:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static readonly ModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider = new ModelExpressionProvider(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider());

    public static string GetExpressionText<TEntity, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return ModelExpressionProvider.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }
}
```

Something to keep in mind is that ModelExpressionProvider holds a ConcurrentDictionary inside for caching, that's why making it static could be beneficial.

As Nenad said, ModelExpressionProvider.GetExpressionText is just a wrapper around ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText with the addition of the cache parameter:

```
public class ModelExpressionProvider : IModelExpressionProvider
{
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<LambdaExpression, string> _expressionTextCache;
    ....
    public string GetExpressionText<TModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression, _expressionTextCache);
    }
    ....
}
```